# Add bottom info bar after the last Card usingCardView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cardview, bottomnavigationview

[image: Im looking to achieve something like on the image.]

I want to add some view element (it really doesn't matter, it could be `TextView`,`Button`, whatever) to the bottom of the screen (above my BottomNavigationBar) to show some info (orange area in the picture). I tried to implement BottomAppBar but this bar belongs to every card in the card view, but I want it to be displayed only once after the last card presented.

Here is my XML of that view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView android:id="@+id/basket_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/basket_image"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            android:id="@+id/comp_title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/basket_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/basket_image" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:id="@+id/remove_btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remove"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/basket_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="anotherInfo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/remove_btn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/comp_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_text_value"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="someTxt"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/some_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/some_title" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I tried to implement some logic in my adapter class like:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(data, position);
    }

    public void bind(Data data, int position) {
            if (data != null) {
               if(data.size() == (position + 1)) {
                   //some methods to set bottom bar to be Visible
                }
                compTitle.setText(...);
                basketImage.setBackgroundResource(...);
           }
      }
```

but no luck.
Could you please give me any advice or maybe there is some element for that purpose? Thank you.

Comment: You can add a item in list as a bottom bar , when you fetch data and add in list then add a item in list which are any widget

Comment: @Avinash like i mentioned above, i already tried that trick but bottom bar attached to every card

Comment: where you add custom item ?

Comment: @Avinash does it matter? Is your question important for you, or do you ask for no reason?

Comment: if you  are fetching from server then when you again fetch list by pagination then remove last item and add it again.

Comment: @Avinash like i answered below, i already resolved that problem.

Comment: sorry for that , i missed your msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive made this by adding different types of ViewHolder’s of my `RecyclerView` and according to its types, create additional itemview for footer (or header). If someone needs more information - tell me and ill paste my code here.